# Add buzzer to multimeter

Tags: multimeter, hacking, continuity, buzzer

How can I add a buzzer to my EverStart Digital Multimeter 10711WDI circuit board, so that it buzzes when there is continuity?

Comment: the 10709WDI has the tone function ... perhaps the 10711WDI has a spot in the circuit for a speaker connection

Answer (score 1):

Realistically, you can't. It is a $16 multimeter. A device like that is not designed for *any* maintenance or upgrades or changes except for replacing the probes (since they plug in) and changing the battery. That's it. This isn't like a computer (well, some computers) with slots for adding features.

There is a *tiny* possibility that the same manufacturer makes a similar meter with a continuity beeper that uses the exact same board except for components missing for additional features. But while that is quite common for much larger/more expensive products (e.g., an oven control panel might be the same for single vs. double, regular vs. convection, etc.), at the low end of the market I find it much less likely. And even if that were the case, by the time you figured out what kind of beeper will work and where to put it, etc. you could work minimum wage somewhere for a couple of hours to buy a meter with more features.

In any case, beeping for continuity is a convenience, not a requirement for most situations.

That meter actually isn't so bad. Unlike some other similarly priced meters at Walmart, this one is marked as ETL listed and CAT III rated. Both of which are good indications of safety. So use it for what it is - an inexpensive but reasonably safe and flexible multimeter that doesn't beep.